# How can I configure write-enabled auto-mounting of NTFS drives?

Tags: macos, mount, ntfs

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3

I'm new to Macs and just encountered the problem, that Macs don't open ntfs formatted external drives by default. 
Well, since I am not new to linux, I just added the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=xxx-xxx-xx none ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

Unfortunatly that did not work. After I plugged in the drive. So I tried to mount it manually by: `mount -a`
That gave me the error message, that `none` does not exist. So I created a folder `/Volumes/external` and changed fstab to:

```
UUID=xxx-xxx-xx /Volumes/external ntfs rw,auto,nobrowse
```

That worked! GREAT!

BUT as soon as I plugged out the drive, the folder was deleted automatically. And after a new plugin of the drive, it could not mount, because the folder was missing.

So my main question is:
**How can I configure write-enabled auto-mounting of NTFS drives?**

Comment: Have you tried using the path that the Finder creates when you plug in the drive when there's no entry in `/etc/fstab` instead of `/Volumes/external`?

Comment: No, I haven't. Good hint. I will try it out this evening and report. Thanks!